# Clicking an AP in network manager causes error "The access point was not in the scan list"

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, intel-wireless

I have a room with pretty weak WiFi signal and my access point has a hidden name, but is correctly configured and saved in network manager.

Sometimes when I lose connection, the AP still appears in the network manager indicator's drop-down menu. Usually this means it is in range again and I can reconnect by clicking, but sometimes trying this pops up a window with this error message:

> **Connection failure**
>
> #### Failed to add/activate connection
>
> (7) The access point /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/AccessPoint/24 was not in the scan list.

Checking `sudo iwlist wlp3s0 scan` confirms that the AP is not in range then, but it refuses to disappear from the indicator menu. Sometimes the entry even survives disabling and re-enabling WiFi and/or networking and even a suspend.

Is this an annoying bug or how can I force network manager to update its scan list properly?

---

**System info:**

Ubuntu 16.04, 64 bit, Unity desktop

Version of package `network-manager`: `1.2.0-0ubuntu0.16.04.3`

From `lshw`:

```
  *-network
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Wireless 3165
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
           logical name: wlp3s0
           version: 81
           serial: 08:d4:0c:b3:0b:19
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=16.242414.0 ip=192.168.178.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
           resources: irq:126 memory:a4000000-a4001fff
```

Comment: I'm sure you've tried `sudo service network-manager restart`, right?

Comment: @AndroidDev Not yet, no. Will do that when it happens the next time though, it should not take too long... :-/

Comment: Sometimes my computer just outright refuses to connect my wireless AP. However, running the previously mentioned command fixes that for me.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If yes, you might want to write an answer

Comment: I don't have a real answer yet @Anwar, restarting the network-manager service is not always helping. However, I found a workaround how I can force continuous refreshing of the scan list, which also helps to detect the AP again quickly after it got lost. I'm running `wavemon` in a terminal and let it scan for available networks (F3).

Comment: It looks like you were the only one with this kind of problem - so I am voting to close this question as a not reproducible problem

Comment: Actually, I do have the same problem trying to connect to a WeWorkWiFi

Comment: Nowadays, you need to restart via `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager` instead.